# Webpack Import Code Splitting rendering <undefined>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, preact

I am trying to do a component based code split. Webpack 3.

```
    loadDecisions = async () => {
    if (!this.TmplDecisions) {
      this.TmplDecisions = await import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "chunk-templates-decisions" */ 'src/components/decisions'
      );
    }

    return this.TmplDecisions;
  }

  renderDecisions () {
    if (this.TmplDecisions && this.TmplDecisions.default) {
      return <this.TmplDecisions.default 
        {...this.props} 
        logOpenEvent={this.logTagOpenEvent}
      />;
    } else return null;
  };
```

The component shows up fine in Dev tools debugger, but it gets rendered as `<undefined></undefined>`

Can someone help?

Comment: Well, everything is fine here.
But the probable point is that where and how the `renderDecisions` is used? is it inside a separate class (something like decisionLoader, or are you using it directly inside another component?
I guess that something is wrong with updating.

Comment: @MojtabaIzadmehr the `renderDecisions` method is being called from `render() -> renderLayout()` method call stack. the `renderDecisions` returns a `VNode` as far as I can see in the Dev tools. still not getting what's happening.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that you never indicate that the component was successfully imported, and to re-render component (this is probably the reason that, you can see its value in the devTools but no render, however, you should face an error if the component is still not imported not <undefined>). Try something simple and check if it changes anything. in `loadDecisions`, just before the return, force update the component with `this.forceUpdate()`.

Comment: It can be a bug in react, please report it there too. Because in no condition should it return <undefined>. React calls the functional components, and creates an instance of class after determining what is the type of the function. So if the component is not a component per se, it should return an error.

Comment: one thing that I have noticed is, no matter what path I give for the component to import, it always imports the chunk. Even if the path is wrong. Thats where things start to get confusing.

Comment: even if using relative pathnames?

Answer (score 0):

Your pathname should start with `./` for dynamic imports of relative modules to work.

eg: `/* webpackChunkName: "chunk-templates-decisions" */ './src/components/decisions.js'` (note `./` here, otherwise webpack treats `src` as npm module).

Comment: Can you create minimum repro on https://codesandbox.io/s/new? It should help us debug issue better.

Answer (score 0):

From the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) :

> You cannot use a general expression as the React element type. If you do want to use a general expression to indicate the type of the element, just assign it to a capitalized variable first.

So try to assign the type to a capitalized variable first.

Also add `TmplDecisions` to the state (or use a flag eg. `tmplDecisionsLoaded` ), so that React re-render after `TmplDecisions` is loaded.

```
  loadDecisions = async () => {
    if (!this.state.TmplDecisions) {
      const TmplDecisions = await import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "chunk-templates-decisions" */ 'src/components/decisions'
      );

      this.setState({ TmplDecisions });
      return TmplDecisions;
    } else {
      return this.state.TmplDecisions;
    } 
  }

  renderDecisions () {
    if (this.state.TmplDecisions && this.state.TmplDecisions.default) {
      const MyComponent = this.state.TmplDecisions.default;
      return <MyComponent
        {...this.props} 
        logOpenEvent={this.logTagOpenEvent}
      />;
    } else return null;
  };
```

Comment: what you mentioned sounds right. but it still isn't working. I still see `<undefined></undefined>`

Comment: Check if you have `export default ...` in `'src/components/decisions'`

Comment: i have export default set in the class.

Comment: what you said is wrong, you can actually simply use a class field as the component, <this.state.TmplDecisions> works just fine, check it out:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not returning a promise at first place which later pass to JSX? 
That would give you undefined.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const TmplDecisions = this.TmplDecisions && this.TmplDecisions.default;
  if (TmplDecisions instanceof Promise) {
    TmplDecisions.then((RealTmplDecisions) => this.setState({ TmplDecisions: RealTmplDecisions}));
    return;
  }
  if (TmplDecisions instanceof Function) {
    this.setState({
      TmplDecisions
    });
    return;
  }
}

// On shouldComponentUpdate you need to check 
// if state.TmplDecisions !== undefined 
// among whatever else you are doing there

renderDecisions () {
  if (this.state.TmplDecisions) {
    return <this.state.TmplDecisions 
      {...this.props} 
      logOpenEvent={this.logTagOpenEvent}
    />;
  } else return null;
};
```